# Why React should have state and prop both

Tags: reactjs

In one context of react article I was told that react should have state and prop both but the reason is not mentioned so why react should have sate and props both

Comment: They are two different things. `state`s are to manage states of a component. Isn't `props` to share properties among components?

Comment: "React *should* have state and prop both". No, it *can* have both but it is not *necessary*.

Comment: Neither state nor props are mandatory. A React component has state and props, but you may decide not to use any because you don't need them. Depending on your use case, you might use only state or only props for that specific component, there are no constraints in this matter. Depending where does the data come from or who it belongs to, using state or props should be enough.